# JSoup doesn't retrieve links on web page

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, jsoup

I'm parsing a sitemap with JSoup.

```
Document dom = Jsoup.parse(new URL(pageRacine).openStream(), "UTF-8", "https://www.lavisducagou.nc/page-sitemap.xml");
Elements liens = dom.getElementsByTag("a");
System.out.println(liens.size() + " links have been retrieved");
```

The output:

`0 links have been retrieved`

I've also tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Document dom = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(new URL("https://www.lavisducagou.nc/page-sitemap.xml").openStream()), "", Parser.xmlParser());
liens = dom.select("a");
```

<strike>Can someone help me</strike> Am I crazy?

**EDIT**: `System.out.println(dom.body());` outputs `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any links, because sitemap has no elements with tag `a`. Urls in sitemap are in tag `loc`. Use `Elements liens = dom.getElementsByTag("loc");`

You were probably mistaken by what you get in the browser. When using browser you get two request. One to download sitemap.xml and second to get main-sitemap.xsl, which contains information for the browser how to display the xml file.

Jsoup does not do that. Use `System.out.println(dom.html())` to see how document downloaded by Jsoup looks like.

Use network tab in your browser to see what elements were downloaded, to display the data.

Comment: In your second attempt you are getting wrong response, because String.valueOf(new URL("https://www.lavisducagou.nc/page-sitemap.xml").openStream()) does not return content of the stream.